# How to insert key/value pairs into a nested dict without overwriting?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am a new programmer using Python 2.75

I have a nested dictionary called `by_sale` in this format:

```
{sale : {days_elapsed: daily_sales_amount}}.
```

For example:

```
{'Spring Savings 0413' : {1 : 3000, 2: 2000, 4:1000}, 
 'Back to School 0812' : {1: 4000, 3:3000, 4:2000}}
```

Note that 'Spring Savings 0413' has no Day 3, and 'Back to School 0812' has no Day 2.

I an trying to create a new dictionary called `by_day` that will store each day and the running total for each sale, even for days with no new sales, like this:

```
{1: {'Spring Savings 0413': 3000, 'Back to School 0812': 4000}, 
 2: {'Spring Savings 0413': 5000, 'Back to School 0812': 4000}, 
 3: {'Spring Savings 0413': 5000, 'Back to School 0812': 7000}, 
 4: {'Spring Savings 0413': 6000, 'Back to School 0812': 9000}}
```

Here is my code:

```
by_day = {}
for sale in by_sale.iterkeys():
    running_total = 0
    for i in range(1,4): #check for each day in the first 4 days
        by_day[i] = {} #initialize a nested blank dictionary for each day
        daily_amount = by_sale[sale].get(i,0) #grab the amount for the day, if none, return a zero
        running_total += daily_amount
        by_day[i][sale] = running # --> I know this is my problem... but why?
print by_day
```

What I get back is only the values for the last sale, which appears to be overwriting the other sales data:

```
{1: {'Back to School 0812': 4000}, 
 2: {'Back to School 0812': 4000}, 
 3: {'Back to School 0812': 7000}, 
 4: {'Back to School 0812': 9000}}
```

I kind of get what is happening here... I just can't figure out how to stop it from happening. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting the entry for each key on every loop using `by_day[i] = {}`. You should rather check for existence of key, in which case, you should update the existing dict.

Or alternatively, use a [collections.`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
>>> by_sale = {'Spring Savings 0413' : {1 : 3000, 2: 2000, 4:1000}, 'Back to School 0812' : {1: 4000, 3:3000, 4:2000}}
>>> 
>>> 
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> 
>>> by_day = defaultdict(dict)
>>> for sale, sale_info in by_sale.iteritems():
...     running_total = 0
...     for i in range(1,5):
...         daily_amount = sale_info.get(i,0)
...         running_total += daily_amount
...         by_day[i].update({sale:running_total})
... 
>>> 
>>> dict(by_day)
{1: {'Spring Savings 0413': 3000, 'Back to School 0812': 4000}, 
 2: {'Spring Savings 0413': 5000, 'Back to School 0812': 4000}, 
 3: {'Spring Savings 0413': 5000, 'Back to School 0812': 7000}, 
 4: {'Spring Savings 0413': 6000, 'Back to School 0812': 9000}}
```

You should use `range(1, 5)` instead. `range(1, 4)` gives - `[1, 2, 3]`.

Comment: You can do `for sale, sale_info in by_sale.iteritems():` and then avoid the other `by_sale[sale]` lookup; you also don't need the running total because you can simply fetch the current amount in the dict.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid. For 2nd case, I think I have to do the test, or use a nested defaultdict. Which would be better?

Comment: `iteritems()` not `iterkeys()`

Comment: @BurhanKhalid. I think running total will be needed, as it is populated in each dict values inside.

Comment: take a look at my answer, to running total, no defaultdict :)

Comment: For python 3, replace `.iteritems()` by `.items()`

Answer (score 2):

here's solution without `defaultdict`:

```
d = {'Spring Savings 0413' : {1 : 3000, 2: 2000, 4:1000}, 
 'Back to School 0812' : {1: 4000, 3:3000, 4:2000}}

r = {}

for s, l in d.items():
    for i in range(1, 5):
        if i not in r: r[i] = {}
        r[i][s] = l.get(i, 0) + r.get(i - 1, {}).get(s, 0)

{1: {'Back to School 0812': 4000, 'Spring Savings 0413': 3000},
 2: {'Back to School 0812': 4000, 'Spring Savings 0413': 5000},
 3: {'Back to School 0812': 7000, 'Spring Savings 0413': 5000},
 4: {'Back to School 0812': 9000, 'Spring Savings 0413': 6000}}
```

Comment: and concise, and that's counts :)